# Prove the limit does not exist in multidimension

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Follow up from my original question,

> Let $f(x, y) = \frac{\mid x\mid}{\mid x\mid + \space y^2}$ for $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$, show that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y)$ does **not** exist.

We can approach along the line $y = mx$ for any $m$.

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x|}{|x| + mx}$$

We approach from the left, $x \to -x$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{-x}{x(m - 1)} = \frac{1}{1 - m}$$

Likewise,

$$\lim_{x \to o^+} \frac{x}{x(1 + m)} = \frac{1}{1 + m}$$

Thus, since the limit from the right does not equal the limit from the lef, the limit does not exist.

Is this a valid explanation?

Comment: Aren't you forgetting the square from $y^\color{red}{2}$...?

Comment: Again, you forget to square the $\;y\,-$ term...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in your first question, you forgot the square of $y^2$. In the earlier question, you already found that approaching $(0,0)$ along any non-vertical line $y=mx$ gave you a limit of $1$. This means the limit is either $1$, or it doesn't exist. If you can find another path resulting in a limit different from $1$, you can conclude the limit doesn't exist.

So far, you only approached $(0,0)$ along **non-vertical** lines; now try the vertical line $x=0$ and let $y \to 0$; what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If $y=\sqrt{|x|} $, the limit will be 
$$\frac {1}{2} $$

and if $y=\sqrt{2|x|} $, it will be

$$\frac {1}{3}. $$

thus ...

Answer (score 0):

For $x>0$ we have

$f(x,0)=1 \to 1$ ($x \to 0+$)

and

$f(x,\sqrt{x})=1/2 \to 1/2$ ($x \to 0+$).